# How to write on an HTML using an input value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i want to understand how Javascript works, i'm a user of **Tornado (Python)** and to put a variable, i use `{{variable}}`, so i just make:

```
<h1> {{variable}} </h1>
```

Now i try to make an HTML edit in a real time, if a user write `1000` for example, there is a somewhere he can see a formatted value, for example `1 000`

in javascript, i can get the value from the console using `document.getElementById("price").value` and then, how do i put in on the HTML code?

Sorry it seems a dumb question.

here is the code:

```
<input id="price" type="number" name="prix" required title="put here..." placeholder="example: 800000" min="1" step="1">
<script>var val = document.getElementById("price").value;
document.getElementById("ggg").innerHTML = val;</script>`<h1 id="ggg">test</h1>`
```

Comment: Depends on where on your page you want to put the data.

Comment: i want to put it on the same page, outside the form, just to help people to see the value they wrote (the formatted one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to modify the [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) attribute of your target element:

```
var val = document.getElementById("price").value;
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = val;
```

You could also modify [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent).

To do the real time part you have to use an event handler, which gets called whenever the value has changed:

```
document.getElementById("price").onchange = function(e){
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

Note that `change` might only fire if the element looses focus. Other events which might be handy are `keypress`, `keydown` or `keyup`, depending on how often you want to update your value.

Comment: so `document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = val` will play the role of `{{val}}`

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: Mostly, yes. However, the concrete structures behind this are part of the DOM. If you modify the `.innerHTML` it will remove all child-nodes which were present in the element, so you should use this method only in elements without children, since they will also loose their event handlers and other added features.

Comment: i'll modify the question and add the code, i'm stuck how to add the variable?

Comment: There's no variable. You have to apply an id to the target element and find that element with `document.getElementById`. If you don't understand one of the terms `id`, `document` or `element` you really need to learn about DOM (and maybe JavaScript in general).

Comment: it worked, thank you, and as you said, i must handle all event:
 `<script>document.getElementById("price").onchange = function(e){
document.getElementById("hhh").innerHTML = this.value;
};
document.getElementById("price").onkeydown = function(e){
document.getElementById("hhh").innerHTML = this.value;
};
</script>`